In Correspondence Analysis, FactoMineR CA, how to understand row.sup/col.sup
In  FactoMineR CA, how to understand the purpose of parameter row.sup/col.sup?
Some example no need row.sup/col.sup and some need. I am confused . Thanks!
  library(FactoMineR)
    data(children)
    res.ca <- CA (children, row.sup = 15:18, col.sup = 6:8)

